# Why is the result of document.getElementsByClassName() empty in jasmine unit test?

Tags: html, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to write a unit test for my angular component. The template contains the following line:

```
<p [innerHTML]="dialogMessage | highlightError | highlightWarning" class="text-left"></p>
```

In the typescript file I modify the dialog message by removing some html tags:

```
const highlightedElements = document.getElementsByClassName('result-element');

if (highlightedElements && highlightedElements.length) {
// some modifications
}
```

The unit test:

```
component.dialogMessage = '<span class="result-element">test</span>';
component.searchString = '';

fixture.detectChanges();

// act
component.search();
```

This code works when used in the program but not in the unit test. In the unit test the `highlightedElements` collection is always empty (it doesn't execute the code in the if block).
Is it because of the `innerHTML`? Or do I have to wait for something to finish loading?
I also tried to return something from the method `document.getElementsByClassName()` by spying on it but then another error occurs.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could please recreate the issue with a stackblitz or something similar. It's easier to help having a minimal working example to look at.

Comment: I've created a Stackblitz example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hr878e?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest%2Ftest.component.spec.ts) but unfortunately it works there. :(

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by 'it works there'? Your test is failing in that stackblitz?

Comment: No, the test is successful. Now I've found out that the test is successful there because I didn't add a pipe in the template (see the first code part here). Why does this fail with the pipe added? Unfortunately I couldn't get the pipe added to the stackblitz yet.